# Documenting C++ static template function with Doxygen

Tags: c++, templates, doxygen

Hi i have a problem with documenting C++ class static template function with Doxygen:

Clazz.h:

```
#ifndef CLAZZ_H
#define CLAZZ_H

/*! \file clazz.h
 *  \brief Clazz declaration
 *  \author Me and myself
 *  \sa Clazz
 */

/*! \class Clazz
 *  \brief About class
 */
class Clazz
{

public:

  /*! \fn TYPE func(TYPE value)
   *  \brief About static func
   *  \param value Parameter
   *  \returns Some value of \c TYPE
   *  \tparam TYPE Class type.
   */
  template<typedef TYPE>
  static TYPE func(TYPE value);
};

#endif
```

Clazz.cpp:

```
#include "clazz.h"

/*! \file clazz.cpp
 *  \brief Clazz implementation
 *  \author Me and myself
 *  \sa Clazz
 */

template<typedef TYPE> 
TYPE Clazz::func(TYPE value)
{
  return value;
}
```

Doxygen shows:

```
Generating docs for compound Clazz...
xxx/clazz.cpp:10: Warning: Member func(TYPE value) (function) of class Clazz is not documented.
```

and when i look at HTML output i can see that function two times:

```
Public Member Functions
template<typedef TYPE> TYPE (TYPE value)

Static Public Member Functions
template<typedef TYPE> static TYPE func (TYPE value)
About func. More...
```

I don't want that non-static documentation.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about Doxygen, but you almost certainly want to define the template in the header. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I could imagine, this might also solve doxygen's confusion here.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a bunch of template functions appearing twice in the documentation, once as static and once not.

I have the function definitions in an `.inl` file (someone prefers to use `.hpp` for this), which is included from the `.h`. I added `EXTENSION_MAPPING inl=c++` to no avail. I have also tried moving the function definition to the `.h` to make sure that Doxygen sees it at the same time it parses the declaration, but that does not help either. This leads me to believe this is a Doxygen bug - upon parsing the member template definition, it is unable to associate it with the appropriate declaration where the `static` keyword appears and clumsily duplicates the function as not static. Well, parsing C++ is no easy task.

I ended up adding the `.inl` file to ignore list as there are no documentation comments in it anyway (except for the documentation of the `@file` itself). Now it does not appear in the file list but that seems like a smaller evil than having bogus member functions appear in the documentation. I suppose you could put all (or at least the problematic ones) the functions in the `.inl` into a `#ifndef DOXYGEN` block and get a perfect result.